# Type Writter effect with HTML tags inside the text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve typing effect which i did but the problem is that the text i have and is being typed inside a `<p>` tag as it's inner HTML has also some HTML tags like `<span></span>` and because the typing is char by char it gets typed out is `<span>` instead of rendered as the element. Is there any way to achieve the effect while keeping the HTML tags as they are? I have highlighted words that are wrapped in spans what i ultimately want to achieve is have the words typed out as highlighted...

```
  function typeWriter() {
    if (i < txt.length) {
      document.getElementById("content_html").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
      i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, self.typing.speed);
    }
  }
  typeWriter();
```

Here is an example of a text i am trying to type out :

```
<p>Surface chemistry deals with phenomena that occur at the surfaces or interfaces. Many important phenomena, noticeable amongst this being corrosion, electrode processes,&nbsp;heterogeneous catalysis, dissolution, and crystallization occur at interfaces. The subject of surface chemistry finds many applications in industry, analytical work, and daily life situations.</p>
```

It contains a `<p>` tag which can in the future change to any other HTML tag since this is coming from the server...

Comment: So to clarify, you want the text inside the `<p>` tag to have the type writer effect. You want any words inside the `<p>` tag that have an anchor tag wrapper around them  to display the same type writer effect - BUT rather than stripping the element of it's anchor properties it will retain them and once the type writer effect has finished you can click on the link as you would expect?

Comment: No i have a parent <p> tag that should contain any text coming from server, but the text from server can contain HTML Tags itself, like words wrapped in spans for some effects...

Comment: How about this workaround using a library. https://jsfiddle.net/we8tchjk/

Comment: @little_coder that library does the right job, but i have one error it never stops typing out the text over and over again, will have to look for the error in its script file

Comment: @little_coder the library does the job perfectly! The error was on my side, i am using Vue.js and it did run in a loop because of the dynamic content render. This is the best option to keep styles, inside tags and dynamic content while achieving the effect, please add this as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Its good challange to write it without additional libraries.  I know we dont have to reinvent the wheel but this quest is interesting.

Comment: I was trying to make it myself. I almost made it but unfortunately everything should be scheduled by time, not only writing letters but creating elements also

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question, but you can also achieve a typing animation with pure CSS as shown in [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/dervondenbergen/pen/fJtch) which could remove some of the issues you are having.

```css
animation: typing 7s steps(15, end), /* # of steps = # of chars */
               blink-caret .5s step-end infinite alternate;
```

Comment: This is a great solution but not dynamic. You have to calculate the length of the string excluding the html markup and then inject or cascade the css with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you are looking for 
`document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "<p>asd</p>";`

instead of `innerHTML`

This way it will render exacly `"<p>asd</p>"` instead of creating an element

Comment: That is true, but when you render character by character the Engine does not understand the openned <p> tags and treats it as text

Comment: Oh so I did not understand you fully. So you want to show `<p` for example but when it happens to be full html it should render html instead ?

Comment: Ok I think I understand. First you would have to parse the text from server, Create elements and then put text into them...

Answer (score 0):

Try This out Where I Am Rendering The Whole Text After You Have Appended Everything In It.

```
<script>
        var i = 0;
        txt = "<p>test this out</p>";
        function typeWriter() {
            if (i < txt.length) {
                document.getElementById("content_html").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
                i++;
                setTimeout(typeWriter, 100);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("content_html").innerHTML = document.getElementById("content_html").innerText;
            }
        }
        typeWriter();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I wanted to make it myself because task is interesting. I know that @little_coder has already provide the best answer in comments to question.

This is what I have done:

js:

```
// text
txt = "asd<p>test this out<span>with more </span>and between text<span class='second'>second</span></p>afe";

//shared array
var instructions = [] ;


// typeWriter
var i = 0; // 
var j = 0;
var elem = '';
var elem_value = '';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {

  if(j < instructions.length){
    if (typeof instructions[j][1] == 'string'){
      if (i < txt.length) {
        instructions[j][0].innerHTML += instructions[j][1].charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
      }else{
        j=j+1;
        i = 0;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
      }
    }
    else if(typeof instructions[j][1] == 'object'){
        console.log("ins", instructions[j][0]);
      instructions[j][0].appendChild(instructions[j][1]);
      j=j+1;
      i=0;
      typeWriter();
    }
  }
}
//  


// recreateNode
parser = new DOMParser();

function recreateNode(list, container){
  doc = parser.parseFromString(list, "text/html");
  doc.body.childNodes.forEach(function(a){
        console.log(a);
    if(a.nodeName == '#text'){
      instructions.push([container, a.nodeValue])     
    }
    else{ // if there is element to create
      b = a.cloneNode(true); // handle deep elements
      c = a.cloneNode(false); // this way I can get ONLY the element with attributes and classes

      /* container.appendChild(c) */; // I append only element
      instructions.push([container, c]);
        recreateNode(b.innerHTML, c); // b will be appended to c

    }
  });

}

// init

parent = document.getElementById("content_html")
recreateNode(txt, parent);
typeWriter();
```

First I created `recreateNode` that creates `instructions` array that stores steps for recreating html structure of the `text`. Using this instructions in `typeWriter` I make `typing effect` or `create html element`. Keeping in instructions `container` value I know where to put next text.

Everything would be ok but when it comes to `.appendChild` or at least I think this is the cause... appending elements takes time that makes `typing effect` not being fluent.

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/an5gzL7f/3/

Thanks in advance for any tips how it could work fast

Answer (score 0):

I just got through a similar challenge while updating TypeIt (https://typeitjs.com) so that it can handle typing nested HTML. In short, the approach I used was repeatedly traversing over all the `childNodes` of the parent element, pulling out each nested node and expanding it into an array of queue items to be later typed.

It got a little hairy working through it all, but if it's helpful, you're welcome to search through the code to see how I'm doing it:

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/typeit/blob/master/src/helpers/chunkStrings.js#L98

A lot of it is very TypeIt-specific -- particularly how I construct objects whose properties contain the information needed to reconstruct those elements.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution is probably the one using the CSS only. However it comes with the downside, that if the text has a line break or is not written in a monospace font, it's basically unpracticable. I took the liberty to write a patch of code to accompany the rest of the solutions that are all useful in their own way.

The downside to my solution is that i used the `textContent` property, which will not render as HTML. I refuse to use innerHTML for security reasons. So adding `<a>` tags is probably not the best idea at the moment.

The goal of my approach is to use the `window.requestAnimationFrame` hook, because it's so powerful. And the rest of the code is still a bit cluttered but at least it's self explanatory.

```
let paragraphNode = document.querySelector('p');
let textObject = {
  actionCounter: 0,
  typeDelay: 6,
  cursorDelay: 22,
  cursorShow: false,
  currentIndex: 0,
  stringLength: paragraphNode.textContent.length,
  textContent: paragraphNode.textContent
}
paragraphNode.textContent = "";

const writeText = ()=>{
  textObject.actionCounter ++;
  if( textObject.actionCounter % textObject.typeDelay == 0 ){
    textObject.currentIndex += 1;
  }
  let string = textObject.textContent.substring(0, textObject.currentIndex);
  if(  textObject.actionCounter % textObject.cursorDelay == 0 ){
    textObject.cursorShow = !textObject.cursorShow;
  }
  paragraphNode.textContent = (textObject.cursorShow) ? string + "|" : string;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(writeText);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(writeText);
```

Here is the codepen example i worked out. The only thing missing at the time of writing is a person brave enough to replace `textContent` with `innerHTML` and possibly check if the next letter is a '<' and add the whole tag at once. Might be tricky though. I strongly recommend against it.

[typewriter on codepen](https://codepen.io/WoobieTheBear/pen/gOgZoVe)